# How to remove duplicate name from array?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this in my .ts file :

```
  search(event) {
    this.autocompletedata.filter((entry) => {
        console.log('entryyyy',entry);
        if (this.showFilter == 1) {
            this.results = entry['items'].filter( a => a['item'] ? a['item'].startsWith(event.query) : false);
        }
        else if (this.showFilter == 2) {
            this.results = entry['items'].filter( a => a['service'] ? a['service'].startsWith(event.query) : false);
        } 
        else if (this.showFilter == 3){
            this.results = entry['items'].filter( a => a['phoneNum'] ? a['phoneNum'].startsWith(event.query) : false);
        }

    });
}
```

Problem is that i get data but i get duplicated data. Any suggestion how can i remove duplicated data from array?

This is my full code for autocomplete.

This is my structure of items :

[image]

Now in last if statement i have results that they are suggestions, and because in array i have multiple times same number i get in suggestion that number and i dont want that- I want only one to be displayed.

Comment: use filter instead of forEach and return true or false based on condition

Comment: i have array in array

Comment: then use filter inside filter. and keep up unitil you get to end!

Comment: when i use filter inside filter i get duplicated names again

Comment: It would be much easier if you provide sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, in your code you using filter for inner items but not for the original array which is the value;

```
  this.result  = this.autocompletedata.filter((entry) => {
        if (this.showFilter == 1) {
            entry['item'] = entry['items'].filter( a => a['item'] ? a['item'].startsWith(event.query) : false);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
  });
```

Comment: adjust to get the actual result

Answer (score 0):

Use array.filter function to filter duplicate array like below:

```
// Array with duplicate names
autocompletedata: Array<string> = ['a','b','v','c','p','a','b']; // For ex
output: Array<string> = []; // this will hold array filtered with duplicate one

let names: string = '';
this.output = this.autocompletedata.filter((item, index) => {
    var flag =  names.indexOf(item)===-1; // check if item available or not
    names = index === this.autocompletedata.length-1? '': `${names}${item}`; // creating string of items to compare duplicate names
    return flag; // return true if item is not duplicate one
})
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation around how your code answers the question? A code dump isn't very easy to learn from

Comment: Updated with explanation.